# BLB Viper - Is this frame OK?

Tags: frames, single-speed, fixed-gear

I want to start building a fixed speed bike and think about having the BLB Viper frame set.

Is it a good frame to start with or would you recommend to get a different ONE, like a Leader frame or a 8bar frame from Germany (both more expensive as the BLB)

THX
LStrike

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I'm afraid that recommendation questions are not [on-topic](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because models and brands change and any answers won't necessarily be valid next year.

Comment: Thx for the hint to the rules, it's hard to find a place, to get a general opinion on this kind of bike parts. The idea of this question was more like, is the Brand itself ok or rubbish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question only invites opinion. The BLB stuff is usually good value for money and well made. I think comparing it to other brands frames that are not often put head to head is tough.

Most of the time with this sort of thing, you get what you pay for and if you want more bling, try something else. But the beauty of most singlespeed/track frames is that the components are pretty much standard, so if you end up not loving it, you can strip off all the components to fit onto a different singlespeed/track frame, and sell the old one. (Obviously check the fine detail!)

Answer (score 0):

The BLB Viper seems good but it has a very unusual seat post construction, in that it doesn't really have one. You cut the frame to the correct saddle height, and attach the saddle to the frame via a special clamp that offers minimal adjustment.

If you cut the post too short, you'll end up with a bike frame that you can't use. I'd only recommend a Viper to someone who knows exactly how high they want their seat.